# How to apply patteren matching on list

Tags: coq

I am applying induction on l'. When perform indcution first time, I come across two case,  [] and n::l'', after second induction n::[],n::n0::t. I want to simplify this, after performing induction two time.

`f1(match l' with
| [] => n
| _ :: _ => high_v (length l')(change n l')
         end + m) (n :: l').`

Comment: For people to help you, they need to know more about ` f1`, `high_v`, `change`, what was the initial goal of your proof, and what is the exact text of tactics that you have entered already.  Also, we need to know which libraries you already imported.  If you give this information, help will be easier to give.

Answer (score 0):

In the current wording of the question, I guess that there exists a type `A` (probably `A` is `nat`), and that functions `change` and `high_v` have types `nat -> list nat -> A` and `nat -> A -> nat` respectively.  If the text is the statement of a current goal, then I guess that `f1` must have type `nat -> list nat -> Prop`.  Can you confirm?

With the current wording of the question, I fear we cannot help you.

Comment: Definition change (n: nat) (l: list nat) : list nat:=
 match l with
 | nil => l
 | h::tl => if n <=? h then l else n::tl
 end.
Fixpoint high_v (elemnt: nat) (l: list nat) : nat :=
 match l with
  | nil => 0
  | cons n nil => n 
  | cons h t => match elemnt with
    | O => h
    | S elemnt' => high_v (elemnt' )(change h t)
    end
 end.
While f1 is function with two input arguments(nat and list nat)
and nat as output.